# Do-calculus and causal inference for continuous random variables

Tags: causality, continuous-data, causal-diagram

Typical treatments of do-calculus and causal inference use discrete random variables. For example, the first rule of do-calculus in Pearl states:

[image]

I'm curious about how the do-calculus and causal inference formulas would change if all variables were continuous random variables. Of course, (3.31) as written would always be true as the probability of a particular y is always zero in a continuous setting. Do we simply take (3.31) and other do-calculus formulas to refer to the probability density rather than the probability?

If anyone has a reference text which formalizes do-calculus in the context of continuous random variables that would also be very helpful.

Comment: You would use cumulative density functions instead of cumulative mass functions.

Comment: @Galen would you mind elaborating or providing an link? I'm not sure what distinction you're drawing. From what I can tell cumulative density functions are a [misnomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_density_function).

Comment: "Cumulative density function" refers to the cumulative distribution function of a continuous random variable. It is a misnomer of sorts because it is not necessarily a density itself and because it is possible for the cumulative distribution of a continuous random variable to exist while a corresponding density function of that random variable may not. Beyond that, read the Wikipedia pages linked on that disambiguation page for how to distinguish between the continuous and discrete cases. Also read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution).

Comment: @Galen Thanks for clarifying! I'm trying to connect CDFs to the do-calculus rules mentioned above. Would you happen to have any references for that specifically (or examples of use)? I suppose you mean that Rule 1 would become something along the lines of Pr(y <= Y | x, z, w) = Pr(y <= Y | x, w). Is this correct? In the case where the density function exists, would we be able to make a statement of the form p(y | x, z, w) = p(y | x, y), where p is now the multivariate pdf?

Comment: Its true that Pearl's textbook focuses on discrete random variables. I was already familiar with continuous random variables (RVs) when I started reading his book. I don't have a reference for you. The good news is (1) the rule above doesn't depend on the RV being discrete and (2) there are lots of resources online (not about causality *per se*) that explain how to compute probabilities for continuous RVs.

Comment: Yes, you would have inequalities in the probability expressions when dealing with CDFs.

Comment: I'm familiar with continuous random variables. If the statement that I made holds, then it also holds that Pr(y_1 <= Y <= y_2 | x, z, w) = Pr(y_1 <= Y <= y_2 | x, w), where y_1 < y_2. Now if we let y_2 -> y_1 from above, we [recover the density function on both sides](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_1_1_pdf.php#:~:text=It%20is%20the%20limit%20of,the%20interval%20goes%20to%200.), such that p(y | x, z, w) = p(y | x, w). This is what I expected, but it's strange that I haven't been able to find this reproduced anywhere, and I am wondering if I've made a conceptual error.